# creating a regex to password validate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with creating a regex to: at least 1 number, only letters in English, at least one special char (@!#$%^&*()-+_), no spaces and not 3 same letters in a row.

ty!

```
    function passwordValidated() {

    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var passMsg = document.getElementById("passMsg");

        if (password.length > 6 && password.length > 12) {
        passMsg.innerHTML = "password must contain above 6 charcters and below 12";
        return false;
    }
        var specialChar = /[@!#$%^&*()-+_]/;
        if (!specialChar.test(password)) {
            passMsg.innerHTML = "password must contain a special character";
            return false;
        }
        var numberCheck = /(?=\S* [\d])/;
        if (!numberCheck.test(password)) {
            passMsg.innerHTML = "password must contain at least one number";
            return false;
        }
    passMsg.innerHTML = "";
    return true;
}
```

this is my code for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
const validators: ((s: string) => true | string)[] = [
    s => s.length >= 6 || "password must contain above 6 charcters and below 12",
    s => s.length <= 12 || "password must contain above 6 charcters and below 12",
    s => /[@!#$%^&*()-+_]/.test(s) || "password must contain a special character",
    s => /\d/.test(s) || "password must contain at least one number",
    s => !/(.)\1\1/.test(s) || "not 3 same letters in a row",
    s => !/\s/.test(s) || "no spaces please",
    s => /^[@!#$%^&*()-+_\w]+$/.test(s) || "only letters in English"
]

function validate (value: string, validators: ((s: string) => true | string)[]) {
    for (let v of validators) {
        let r = v(value);
        if (r !== true) return r;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log([
    validate('asd', validators),
    validate('asdhakufhskuydgsiyug', validators),
    validate('asdj$hgsd', validators),
    validate('asdj$4h gsd', validators),
    validate('asdj$4hgsd', validators),
])
```

Inspired by Quasar (Vue framework) imput field validation

Comment: i tried putting a no space error and it keeps telling me the only english letters error can you help me?

Comment: Here you go.```` ```

Comment: i also need a regex to say that if i wrote in hebrew i can't write in english and the other way too pls

Comment: `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` iirc, i.e. english

Comment: can you explain it a little bit easier pls?

Comment: `'a-zA-Z0-9_Й^#*@&#'.match(/\w/g) // ["a", "z", "A", "Z", "0", "9", "_"]`. So, `\w` test for if the char is english letter OR digit OR underscore, `@!#$%^&*()-+_` for all other allowed chars, and `/^[@!#$%^&*()-+_\w]+$/` means that "since beginning, to end, all characters are in list: `@!#$%^&*()-+_` or `\w`(A-Z,a-z,0-9)"